# How to add an element with jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to know how to add an HTML element with jQuery or Javascript after another element

for example, 
from this

```
<ul>
<li> .... </li>
<li> .... </li>
<li> .... </li>
</ul>
```

to this

```
<ul>
<li> .... </li>
<div>..</div>
<li> .... </li>
<div>..</div>
<li> .... </li>
<div>..</div>
</ul>
```

Comment: I would look at jquery after(), http://api.jquery.com/after/

Comment: I tried  the append() Method and after()

Comment: That is invalid HTML so the answer is NO

Comment: nothing work to me because when i used
the element be After all the ul
and i want it After every ul

Comment: Do you understand the issue after reading my answer below? A div can not be a child of a UL so you can not add the div after the li in the DOM tree. The ul expects to find li's as the children. When you try to add the div, it will try to figure out the  best fit and it is probably adding the new div after the UL.

Comment: yes yes i understand you 
tnx you for this informations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not append a `div`as a child of a `UL` so no you can not add the `div` element after the `li`. The browser will "fix" your bad HTML the best as it can and not every browser will do the same thing.

If you append and `li` that has a `div` as a child, it will work correctly.

```js
$("li").after("<li><div>New</div></li>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li> .... </li>
    <li> .... </li>
    <li> .... </li>
</ul>
```